# Not all code paths return a value - where?

Tags: c#

I have the following C# code. For reasons I won't go into, this is the required way of localising.

My problem is, I cannot for the life of me figure out what path is not returning a value. There are no other errors in the below code:

```
ResourceManager ResMain = new ResourceManager("TorrentSched.Main", typeof(Main).Assembly);
/// <summary>Returns a localised string based on the Current UI Culture</summary>
public string Str(string Name)
{
    Boolean StringNotFound = false;
    switch(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString())
    {
        case "en-GB":
            switch(Name)
            {
                case "MinimizeToTray": return "Closing the program minimises it to the tray. To fully quit the program, right-click the icon in your tray and choose Exit.";
                default: StringNotFound = true; break;
            }
        break;
        default:
            StringNotFound = true;
        break;
    }

    if(StringNotFound)
    {
        StringNotFound = false;
        switch(Name)
        {
            case "AppName":         return ResMain.GetString("$this.Text");
            case "MinimizeToTray":  return "Closing the program minimizes it to the tray. To fully quit the program, right-click the icon in your tray and choose Exit.";
            case "ReallyExit1":     return "Do you really want to exit?";
            case "ReallyExit2":     return "Torrents will not be checked and downloaded until you launch the program again!";
            default:                return "String not found!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the function presented **is not complete**. There is a problem on the bottom of the code, I guess.

Comment: @Tigran I missed a single `}` - edited.

Comment: What is the purpose of the if-block? As far a I can see, if code below the switch is executed, `StringNotFound` will always be true, so the if-block is not necessary, but it may very well confuse the code analysis.

Comment: @FredrikMörk That's the perfect point! Make that an answer and I'll choose that!

Comment: You don't have a return statement for the `else` condition. You don't need the if condition at all. The simple solution to this problem is have a single return outside of the `if` condition.  I suggest you post on the code review stack exchange website there several bad habits outlined in this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the purpose of the if-block? As far a I can see, if code below the switch is executed, `StringNotFound` will always be `true` so the if-block is not necessary, but it may very well confuse the code analysis.

Comment: Perfect answer. Strange though that Visual Studio doesn't realise that `StringNotFound` will never be false, therefore all code paths return a value.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Doing that level of analysis is hard to do and would slow the compilation time (see "The Halting Problem"). So it's a compromise between accuracy and time. Here, the compiler sees a return in the true block and no equivalent in the (missing) else block with no final return. So it assumes there's a possible path that can have no return value. It's not smart enough (by design) to statically analyse the code.

Answer (score 4):

If StringNotFound is false, you don't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

At the very end of your method, if `StringNotFound` is false:

```
if(StringNotFound)
{
   [...]
}

// missing return statement here
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could refactor it so that at the bottom of your code you have a SINGLE return statement. And all your decision-making code simply 'sets' the return value.

Then in your switch(Name) block SET the value of what you want to return - then break out of the switch (rather than having a whole bunch of returns). IMO, this would make the code neater. Also, I think it'd make it easier to maintain.

ie.

```
switch(Name)
        {
            case "AppName":         retString = ResMain.GetString("$this.Text");
            case "MinimizeToTray":  retString = "Closing the program minimizes it to the tray. To fully quit the program, right-click the icon in your tray and choose Exit.";
            case "ReallyExit1":     retString = "Do you really want to exit?";
            case "ReallyExit2":     retString = "Torrents will not be checked and downloaded until you launch the program again!";
            default:                retString = "String not found!";
        }

...

return retString;
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent mistakes or puzzles like this, you better not do both of this (below) , as there is no single logical flow anymore when you:

- Maintain a `retVal` variable, together with
- Multiple uses of the `return` statement.

Choose one solution:

- only return a `retVal` variable, or
- return a default at the bottom of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a dictionary

```
private static Dictionary<string,string> stringDict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

Add the strings

```
// Add default strings
stringDict.Add("AppName", ResMain.GetString("$this.Text"));
stringDict.Add("MinimizeToTray", "Closing the program ...");
stringDict.Add("ReallyExit1", "Do you really ...");

// Add culture specific strings
stringDict.Add("en-GB;AppName", ResMain.GetString("$this.Text"));
stringDict.Add("en-GB;MinimizeToTray", "Closing the program ...");
stringDict.Add("en-GB;ReallyExit1", "Do you really ...");
```

The you can get the strings very quickly with

```
// Get culture specific string
string culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString();
string s;
If (stringDict.TryGetValue(culture + ";" + Name, out s)) {
    return s;
}                          

// Get default
If (stringDict.TryGetValue(Name, out s)) {
    return s;
}

return String.Format("String '{0}' not found!", Name);
```

This is easier to maintain.

(As other have already pointed out, there is a return-statement missing at the very end of your method and the boolean variable is superfluous.)

Answer (score 0):

if(StringNotFound)

If this is false there is no else statment to catch it.

use

> if(StringNotFound)
>   {
>       //your code
>   }
>   Else
>   {
>   return "String not found!";
>   }

Comment: There is an error in this code.  Its a single character so I can't propose an edit.

Comment: yer should make more senes now :)